# How to take elements from each line of a file, and prepend them to each entry in each line of a different file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, data-science

I'm trying to join two datastructures. I feel like this should be a simple enough task in bash, but I haven't managed to succeed so far.

I have two data files: file_1 is a list of identifiers; and file_2 is a list of tab-separated entries, where each entry consists of three numeric strings separated by commas (example file below). I'd like to append (or prepend) the string in each line in file_1 to the beginning of each numeric string in each line in file_2, e.g.

file_1 looks like this:

```
id_1
id_2
id_3
```

file_2 looks like this:

```
1234,543,134    210,1676,8  26,20,6
789,33400,342   8291,3390,890
772,602,3   224,220,1   407,405,2   8,895,7 985,93,4    96,93,3 145,145,3
```

I would like to have:

```
id_1,1234,543,134   id_1,210,1676,8 id_1,26,20,6
id_2,789,33400,342  id_2,8291,3390,890
id_3,772,602,3  id_3,224,220,1  id_3,407,405,2  id_3,8,895,7    id_3,985,93,4   id_3,96,93,3    id_3,145,145,3
```

file_1 and file_2 always have the same number of lines. In file_2, each comma-separated numeric string is always [digits],[digits],[digits] but there can be a variable number of strings on each line, and a variable number of digits within each string.

#### What I've done so far

So far, I've managed to prepend each entry with a constant value, by adding a tab to the start of each line in file_2, then using gsub to replace each tab with the constant I want, e.g. `( printf '\t'; cat file_2.txt ) | awk '{ gsub("\t",",\tconstant,"); print }'`, which results in

```
,   constant,1234,543,134,  constant,210,1676,8,    constant,26,20,6
789,33400,342,  constant,8291,3390,890
772,602,3,  constant,224,220,1, constant,407,405,2, constant,8,895,7,   constant,985,93,4,  constant,96,93,3,   constant,145,145,3
```

and from there I can clean up the unwanted comma and tab at the start.

I wanted to build on this by using a `while read` loop over file_2 and using each line number as a variable, e.g.

```
while read; do 
line=$(awk '{ print NR}')
id_to_add=$(awk -v line=$line 'NR == line' file_1)
( printf '\t'; cat file_2.txt ) | awk -v id=${id_to_add} '{ gsub("\t",",\tid,"); print }'
done < file_2
```

However, this doesn't work because the variable $line is simply all the lines in file_2, rather than going through line by line, i.e. `echo $line` returns `1 2 3`

I feel like there should be a cleaner way to do this, perhaps using awk's two-file processing, `awk 'NR==FNR' file_1 file_2` ?

Thanks!

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=($0 ",");next} {OFS=("\t" a[FNR]);$1=(a[FNR] $1)} 1' file1 file2
```

It simply updates the records in second file by

1. prepending the first field with corresponding *id* from the first file,
2. appending said *id* to field separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = a[FNR] "," $i} 1' file1 file2
id_1,1234,543,134 id_1,210,1676,8 id_1,26,20,6
id_2,789,33400,342 id_2,8291,3390,890
id_3,772,602,3 id_3,224,220,1 id_3,407,405,2 id_3,8,895,7 id_3,985,93,4 id_3,96,93,3 id_3,145,145,3
```